# Regex search for Edge version in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to figure out if a user is using Microsoft Edge, and if so, what version of Edge it is. I know I can get the version using `navigator.userAgent`, and in my own Edge browser that returns 
`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134`.

Seeing if "Edge" is there in the string given by `userAgent` is pretty simple, but I was wondering what the regex command would be to get the version so that I can compare it and see if it's less than a certain version (18.17763 in my case)? I would be using the string.match() method. I have not used regex before, so I have no idea what the expression would be.

Comment: Why? What do you need to know this for?

Comment: seems like a basic regular expression

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol there's a bug with Javascript event listeners in Edge, and was fixed in EdgeHTML 18.17763. I need to be able to handle the bug in older versions.

Comment: Can you detect this bug in some other way? What is the bug anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edge/(\d+.\d+)

First capture group and parse. Next time try regex101.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers are moving away from exposing their versions in User Agent strings. Some browsers (I believe Firefox) have already "frozen" their User-Agent strings. So even if you get this to work, it will soon be irrelevant.

Use feature detection instead.

Comment: Would feature detection still work in my case if the feature is there, but has a bug and does not work properly? Here's the bug https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/12224510/

Comment: It looks like the "bug" just results in progress indication not working for that particular version? I don't think that's such a huge issue - after all, older browsers don't even support progress events at all.